# How to include angular-calendar (mattlewis92) as an Angular component not as a package

Tags: angular, angular-calendar

We are using [angular-calendar (mattlewis92)](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/). As we want to have more control over the calendar, we want to include it as an Angular component, and not as a package.

I included all the `modules` (in the picture), `calendar-utils` folder, but there are endless number of errors, I fix one, I get another 10 errors.

was anyone able to create an Angular Component out of the packages smoothly? is there a tuturial somewhere I can read?

[image]

Edit: The app is finally compiling, however I am getting the following error:
[image]

Comment: mention your errors here can help to solve your problem.

Comment: `As we want to have more control over the calendar, we want to include it as an Angular component, and not as a package.` -> i think for having more control, you should somehow put that module in your project source forlder. not converting it to a commponent.

Comment: @ng-hobby I included a screenshot for the error

Comment: @yaya Yeah sorry that's what I did. I put the modules in the src folder :)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e.g. as Stackblitz to investigate your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't including the right calendar-utils.ts file. the source file is [here](https://github.com/mattlewis92/calendar-utils/blob/master/src/calendar-utils.ts)
You can include the whole file or just what you want from it; in my case for example I just wanted to include the MonthView functions, because I am only interested in a monthly view calendar. So I just included `MonthViewDay`, `MonthView`, `GetMonthViewArgs`, `ViewPeriod`, `getMonthView`.

Also he uses dateAdaptor classes which gives you the possiblity to choose between `date-fns` and `moment.js` I removed the whole folder and replaced it everywhere with the corresponding `date-fns`functions.

The last step I did was to include the pipes for date formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `NullInjectorError` properly your provider for `CalendarUtils` is missing in your `module`.

Have a look at the [original](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/blob/master/projects/angular-calendar/src/modules/calendar.module.ts) `calendar.module.ts` impl. where the provider is defined.

E.g.:

```
      providers: [
        dateAdapter,
        config.eventTitleFormatter || CalendarEventTitleFormatter,
        config.dateFormatter || CalendarDateFormatter,
        config.utils || CalendarUtils,
        config.a11y || CalendarA11y,
      ],
```

Comment: The problem was indeed the calendarUtils, I was just includeing the wrong files. Check my unswer below if you want to know more details. Thanks for the answers I rewareded it with the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.module.ts` and in the `providers` add this:

```js
providers: [
  CalendarUtils
]
```